# How to submit additional Form Data to Blueimp Uploader?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, blueimp

I am trying to insert additional Form Data to MYSQL via Blueimp jquery file uploader. But I have some problems.

I am using demo settings and I changed my template-upload to following code (* I added Notunuz input)

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="title"><label>Notunuz: <input name="title[]"></label></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Hata</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
            <td>
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Başlat</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}

    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

- How to get additional Form Data?
- How to change `.js` and `UploadHandler.php` file?

---

My second question is *How to redirect to specific URL upload is done?*

Comment: second q-n is simple add to `done` handler something like `location.href=new_url`

Comment: [how to submit additional form data](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data) from plugin documentation....

Comment: Thanks for your helps. How do you retrieve title server side through UploadHandler.php? I need to know this.

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and you will see all data that you sent

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways for sending additional FormData,

1.Static Form Data (If the formdata are never changed on runtime) :

Initialize FileUpload using ,

```
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({
         formData: {
            "data1": data1,
            "data2": data2
        }
     });
```

2.Dynamic FormData

Use `fileuploadsubmit` for setting FormData on submit event

```
$('#formData').fileupload({
   .........
}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    data.formData = {
         "data1": data1,
         "data2": data2
    };
});
```

For More Details See :

- [How to submit additional form
  data](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data)
- [How to retrieve and set form data
  asynchronously.](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Submit-files-asynchronously)

Answer (score 1):

I used like,

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    formData: {example: 'test'}
});
```

To be more dynamic,

```
 <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="inpName" /> /* example 1 */
 <span id="spnHash" style="display:none">ttt-vvv-hh</span> /* example 2 */
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    var $formData = {
        "name": $("#inpName").val(),
        "hash": $("#spnHash").text()
    }
     formData: $formData
 });
```

For redirect:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/670#issuecomment-2291997

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#file-upload').fileupload({
      formData: {key: 'value'}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an input element inside the fileupload form like the following:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="/server/php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="additional_data" value="your_value" hidden >
</form>
```

Then inside the UploadHandler.php you can get the value of your input using
$_REQUEST['additional_data']

for example:

```
$myData = $_REQUEST['additional_data'];
```

and then insert data to mysql:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->query("INSERT INTO your_tbl(your_field) VALUES ('$myData')");
```